# Disable a button based on condition

Tags: html, angular, html-table, angular10

I am getting data from a server and I want to filter out a particular column. What I want is that if a column bought(boolean) says true I must disable the edit  button sideby if its false the edit  must be shown

enter code here

```
            <div *ngIf="isbaker">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="table_header">
                <tr>
                    
                    <th>Customer</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Bought</th>
     
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let baker of shop;">            
                    <td>{{  baker.customer }}</td>
                    <td>{{ baker.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{  baker.bought}}</td>
               
                    

                    <td  *ngIf="isButton">
                        <button mat-icon-button matTooltip=" Edit" class="iconbutton" (click)="isbakerEdit(baker)"
                            color="primary">
                            <mat-icon style="color: gray;" aria-label="Edit">edit</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </td>  
                </tr>
            </tbody> 
        </table>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <button mat-icon-button matTooltip=" Edit" class="iconbutton"(click)="isbakerEdit(baker)" 
       color="primary" [disabled]="baker?.bought">
       <mat-icon style="color: gray;" aria-label="Edit">edit</mat-icon>
   </button>
```

All what you have to do is to call this `[disabled]="baker?.bought`

Comment: It works but I want the button to do a mouse hover when its enabled and not hovered when its disabled

Answer (score 2):

You can use the disabled directive provided by Angular.

```html
<td  *ngIf="isButton">
   <button mat-icon-button matTooltip=" Edit" class="iconbutton"(click)="isbakerEdit(baker)" 
       color="primary" [disabled]="baker.bought == true">
       <mat-icon style="color: gray;" aria-label="Edit">edit</mat-icon>
   </button>
</td>
```

Comment: It works but I want the button to do a mouse hover when its enabled and not hovered when its disabled

Comment: Do you want to toggle hover property on a button based on a condition? What do you want to do after that?

Comment: Yeah exactly I just wanna be able to hover when its enabled and vice versa. The button which is diabled cannot be hovered